# How do I trace who delete the sites and its content if I am the owner of the site but not the Administrator?

Tags: delete

I am a owner of three sites, which all of them are sub-sites. I am also not the administrator of the "root" site (which contain many sub-sites including the three sites that I am the owner of it).

Today, one of my sites was "vanished" (which I believe that someone had delete it). How do I trace who delete my site? (Do note that I am NOT the Administrator of the SharePoint Server and the Administrator will not entertain any request from sub-sites owner to check on Server logs)

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way of finding out unless someone checks the logs to see what happened when, why and by who.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users deleting sites accidentally (or intentionally but later requiring data from them) is a bit of an issue in SharePoint. This is because, in contrast to smaller chunks of data (e.g. list items, pages, files etc.), the site is permanently deleted rather than going into the recycle bin.

So, when this happens, admins must get the backups out, restore the entire backup to an environment somewhere, then move the particular site back to the right place using STSADM. This can be time-consuming.

It's possible to put together a solution for this, but the good news is Microsoft have done it for you. They developed a tool for for solving this problem internally which has now been released on Codeplex. This is known as the Site Delete Capture tool, and when a user deletes a site it captures this event and backs the particular site up to disk (i.e. not the entire farm/web application/site collection).

It's linked to from http://www.codeplex.com/governance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your site is in the Recycle Bin and you find the person in the "deleted by" column. Make sure to check the

- "normal" recycle bin (.../_layouts/recyclebin.aspx)
- Site collection recycle bin (.../_layouts/AdminRecycleBin.aspx) and the
- "Deleted from end user recycle bin" (.../_layouts/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2)

Comment: Unfortunately, all the recycle bin was totally empty. I was wondering if there are other method to trace.